# How to find distinct average of column values in quiver or workshop or using typescript

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have a dataset in which I need to find the distinct average i.e. sum of distinct values of B column (type: double) by count of distinct values of column A (type: string).

I couldn't find a way to calculate distinct average in quiver or workshop. However, I can able to use a typescript function but there is a 10,000 record limit. How can I calculate?

For example if I have a data like

| person | Age |
| --- | --- |
| A | 40 |
| A | 40 |
| A | 40 |
| A | 40 |
| B | 50 |

I want the average as (40+50)/2 instead of (40+40+40+40+50)/5 and I am trying to accomplish this in quiver or workshop.